# Real time Local Maximum Finder

Tags: vhdl

of course for this question i don't want a exact solution. Only ideas or a little guide (i mean experienced ones! ) is enough. As the graph shows, i have a real time signal already simulated in matlab. The length of signal is almost large, not fixed yet, but something around 100 KBytes. It is a real time signal and every point will be calculated on the positive edge of CLK. The task is to find the maximum of the signal. Some points that may help are that the length of real signal is also fixed (I mean the main shape, except zero parts), and the distance between the peaks is supposed to be constant and known before. So, to Generalize : We have a fixed window frame (lets say 100 KBytes), and there is a fixed size signal (lets say 50 KBytes) in a random position. We need the time of occurrence of the largest peak.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!
[image: real time signal]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like comparator business:
You just hand every point of the signal - represented by a binary number - to an comparator. The comparator compares the value of the signal with a register holding the largest value found up to now (initially 0 at t=0). If the signal value is larger than the value in the register store the current input in the register (optionally together with the time index) and discard the old value. If the input value is less than the register value proceed with the next point of the signal.